# iphone add framework

Tags: iphone

I have added CFNetwork.framework,but when I import the header file "CFNetwork.h",it said"CFNetwork.h:no such file or directory"[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of these will work: Import the top level header instead.

```
#import <CoreServices/CoreServices.h>
```

Or

```
#import <CFNetwork/CFNetwork.h>
```